# 9 speed chain doesn't fit 9 speed cassette

Tags: maintenance, chain, drivetrain

In all my years of working on bikes, this is a first. Bought a new 9 speed KMC chain and 9 speed cassette to replace a worn 9 speed drivetrain recently (single chain ring). Went to put everything on tonight, except the new chain is way too short -- even on the smallest cog the derailleur is so stretched I'm afraid turning the cranks will rip it off the hanger.

Comparing the new chain to the old chain (also a 9 speed chain, in case it isn't clear) shows that the new chain is about six inches shorter. I don't know how many links are in the old chain, but the new chain supposedly has 116 links and the highest link chain I can find on the internet is 120. I've never had so much difficulty overhauling a 9 speed drivetrain before.

Can anyone explain what the hell is going on here? I've got pictures on my phone I can include if the description doesn't make sense.

Comment: The length of chain in inches or millimetres isn't that important - what matters is the number of links has to be identical to the old chain.   Photos might help clarify the cause, so yes please add your pictures.

Comment: You'll need to count the links. Maybe you've been given a 112 link chain instead. Both my main bikes need quite long chains (long chainstays and wide gear ranges) but need no more than 118 links

Comment: The replacement chain is too short!

Comment: Two same # speed chains can differ in the number of links / chain length. The # speed concerns chain width and its ability to bend sideways. When looking for a replacement you also need to consider how many links you need depending on your frame size and cogs and chainrings sizes.

Comment: Spoke with my local bike mechanic wizard. "9 speed" is a misnomer and largely has to do with the distance between the rollers, not the length of the chain. I thought it was the latter.

Comment: The ''speed' description of a chain is not a misnomer. 8, 9, 10, 11  speed chains differ mostly in the *external* width of the chain which gets progressively narrower (the *internal* width between the inner plates is constant at 2.4mm.) The external width decreases because the separation of sprockets gets narrower as the number of sprockets goes up. All bicycle chain has a pitch of 1/2".

Comment: Suggest you revisit this next time you're talking with your wizard - there's been some misunderstanding.  Argenti is correct.   I have a 10 speed chain with ~270 links in it, but this is still 10 speed chain with a nominal outer plate width of 5.88 mm   Some good pictures at https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1220/1-bicycle-chains-compatibility/

Comment: He was citing distances down to a thousandth, so I trust he knows what he's talking about. It is a misnomer in this situation as I previously explained, so I'm not sure what lying about this or trying to mislead me is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: In any case the original question is about the chain length, not its width. Specification of "speeds" in the title is misleading — OP thought it was important to mention it, but it in fact does not affect the correct answer, which is "chain length is too short".

Comment: Weird to specify the distance between rollers in thousandths, since it's always 1/2" or 12.7mm

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple - the new chain is too short. Maybe you bought a chain with too few links, maybe it's a production error.

The pitch (distance between pin centers) of bicycle chain is 1/2", so it's easy to count links by measuring.

Chain length required is determined by chainstay length and largest chainring and sprocket size. Usually you get a chain a few links too long and cut it to size and re-join. When replacing a chain you can use the old chain to size the new one. If the old chain is lost chain length can be determined by fitting to the bike. Park Tool has a good video on how to do that.

Comment: As an example: a new chain with 116 links was too short for my 1× conversion — the position on the biggest rear cog was stretching the derailleur too much. A chain with 118 links was just fine. If a setup has a huge front chainring (40t), the rear cassette has similarly huge biggest cog (now one can have 50t for 9-speed (sic!)), and the chainstay length is big, one may need first to connect two regular chains, and then cut it to make a chunk long enough. Or maybe get a custom length chain, if that's a thing: tandem bicycles do need to have even longer chains.